# "Not well-formed" error from XML::Simple

Tags: perl, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse some XML that contains a namespace but [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) is throwing an error.

> ```
> not well-formed (invalid token) at line 3, column 53, byte 63
> ```

```
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $string = q(
<result>
<something id="207" xlink:href="http://someurl.com&op=yeah">Something 207</something>
</result>
);

print Dumper(XMLin($string));
```

Is there a way I can get this to work with `XML::Simple`? Or do I have to use a different XML parsing library?

Comment: That's not valid XML -- there's a `&` that does not denote the start of an entity -- thus the error.

Comment: @ikegami What part of it is invalid?

Comment: Note that XML::Simple is a pretty poor choice if you want to deal with namespaces

Answer (score 2):

***Please take note of the warning*** in the [documentation for `XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple), which reads as follows:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) is highly recommended and [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) is an excellent alternative.

XML documents may not contain ampersands `&` or angle brackets `<` `>` outside CDATA sections. Within ordinary (PDATA) data sections and attribute values they need to be replaced by *entities* `&amp;` `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively

Your program is correct and your data is malformed. Character 53 of line 3 is here

```
<something id="207" xlink:href="http://someurl.com&op=yeah">Something 207</something>
                                                    ^
                                                Column 53
```

so it is reporting the `p` (because `&op` isn't the start of any known entity) and the problem is nothing to do with namespaces

My version of `XML::Simple` (currently the most recent version 2.22) gives a more explicit message

> ```
> Entity: line 3: parser error : EntityRef: expecting ';'
> <something id="207" xlink:href="http://someurl.com&op=yeah">Something 207</somet
>                                                      ^
> ```

You can fix things by replacing the ampersand with its entity, like this

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;
use XML::Simple;

my $string = <<END_XML;
<result>
  <something id="207" xlink:href="http://someurl.com&amp;op=yeah">Something 207</something>
</result>
END_XML

dd XMLin($string);
```

#### output

```
{
  something => {
    "content" => "Something 207",
    "id" => 207,
    "xlink:href" => "http://someurl.com&op=yeah",
  },
}
```